# Undesired behaviour of wildcard routes in CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, command-line-interface, flatiron.js

I've the following routes in my CLI app:

```
system
system *
system info
system info *
system settings
system settings *
system tunables
system tunables *
system logging
system logging *
system logging settings
system logging settings *
```

and want a behaviour like this:

- if entered `system` command -> exec `system` handler
- if entered `system ANYTHING_BUT_CONFIGURED_ROUTES` command -> exec `system *` handler, being `ANYTHING_BUT_CONFIGURED_ROUTES` anything else but:

  info
  settings
  tunables
  logging

The issue is related `app.cmd()` execution order:

- if I register the routes in inverse order than above the handlers are executed properly
- if I register the routes in the same order than above, if I execute `system info`, the handler for `system *` is triggered instead of `system info`.

Any suggestion on how overcome this?

I'm solving this currently by looping and contructing an inverse array and then looping again, but this takes a lot of time for a simple CLI app and this is cumbersome, so I'm looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the modules you use, the problem makes sense, it's matching on first found, not most specific... but you don't have to completely rearrange your list, just put the wildcards after the specific entries, like so:

```
system
system info
system info *
system settings
system settings *
system tunables
system tunables *
system logging
system logging settings
system logging settings *
system logging *
system *
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using `flatiron`, see tags ;) On your solution, that is almost the same I'm doing now (mine is easier to implement, tough). What I'm asking for is to provide a solution that fix that behaviour someway without to hack on the order.

Comment: I'm using the flatiron cli plugin.

Comment: I see you're using flatiron, I just don't have experience with it, but I did look it up. The behavior isn't "broken", it's efficient.  It stops looking when it finds a match. Your solution, however, is broken, because it will execute `system logging *` when you attempt to execute `system logging settings`. Ultimately the routing logic comes from [director](https://github.com/flatiron/director), if you see anything in there that lets you route to most specific instead of first found then that's what you're looking for, but I didn't see anything.

Comment: My solution isn't broken, I tested it properly. Check https://gist.github.com/diosney/10129855 and do a `node app.js system logging settings` to verify it. Yeah, I checked `director` too but didn't find anything related (the `backward & forward` settings aren't what I'm after).

Comment: It seems this is not a simple question after all. I will ping flatiron devs directly then. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct, when you do a strict reverse then it does go from more specific to less all the way down.